# Multiple persistence unit on Wildfly

Tags: java, jpa, persistence.xml

I'm using JPA with Wildfly and I am connecting to multiple databases. Below is the persistence.xml -

```
<persistence-unit name="ContiegoDS" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ContiegoDS</jta-data-source>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/orm-legacy.xml</mapping-file>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/queries/native.xml</mapping-file>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQLSpatial56Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor" value="org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />

    </properties>   
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="ContiegoWebsiteDS" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ContiegoWebsiteDS</jta-data-source>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/orm-website.xml</mapping-file>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQLSpatial56Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor" value="org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>   
</persistence-unit>
```

I'm calling it this way

```
public class ContiegoEJB {

   @PersistenceContext(unitName="ContiegoDS")
   protected EntityManager contiegoEntityManager;

   @PersistenceContext(unitName="ContiegoWebsiteDS")
   protected EntityManager contiegoWebsiteEntityManager;

   public ContiegoEJB() {
   }

}
```

But I'm getting this error

[image: Here is the error log I can't post more code-text in the question]

Comparisson between orm and orm-website.xml files

[image]

AdminUser and AdminUserPasswordRecovery entities...
[image: AdminUser and AdminUserPasswordRecovery entities.]

Relation many to one from AdminUserPasswordRecoveryRequest to AdminUser
[image]

What can I possible doing wrong?

Comment: Post more from your error message.

Comment: Added as a image ... Thanks for your time :)

Comment: and what can you say about the entity it is complaining about "AdminUser" ?

Comment: Is properly mapped on orm.xml (ContiegoDS), but is never mapped on orm-website.xml (ContiegoWebsiteDS) because the entity is not present or used on this DB. So I can't understand why this entity can be a problem... I remove ContiegoWebsiteDS from my persistence.xml file and works fine. In fact, I change orm-website.xml to orm.xml and seems to work good (but has no my entities mapped from the other DB)

Comment: I updated my question adding my orm files